# How to query array stored column in Postgres, (array intersection)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table which contains value in array something like this.

```
id | contents_id
 1 | [1, 3, 5]
 2 | [1, 2]
 3 | [3, 4, 6]
 4 | [2, 5]
```

How to write a query array e.g. `[1, 2]` such that it check value of array not array as a whole ?

If any common value of array is found get all tuples.

If `[1, 2]` is queried it must fetch `id` => `1, 2, 4` from above table as it contains `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the intarray extension. It provides a && operator for testing integer array overlapping. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d7434/1) is a fiddle, with an example.

```
select id from test where ARRAY[1,2] && contents_id;
```

Though you can query it with the operator, I think it will be better to make a junction table with integer IDs.

Comment: should I add `intarray` extension? separately to query this way? happy to see working code in fiddle. thanks for that.

Comment: If it isn't added yet, you must create it on your server. You can see how to do it in the fiddle's code. I commented it out since it's already installed on those servers.

Answer (score 2):

On 1-D int arrays `&&` operator `arrayoverlap` is the fastest as @LaposhasúAcsa suggested.

so my answer stands only if `arrayoverlap` is not avaliable or want to work with anything other than one dimensional integer arrays.

Check `UNNEST` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

```
CREATE TABLE t45407507 (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,c int[]
);
insert into t45407507 ( c) values
    (ARRAY[1,3,5])
  , (ARRAY[1,2])
  , (ARRAY[3,4,6])
  , (ARRAY[2,5]);

select DISTINCT id from 
  (SELECT id,unnest(c) as c
  from t45407507) x 
where x.c in (1,2);
```

Can be shortened with `LATERAL` join

```
select DISTINCT id from
   t45407507 x,unnest(c) ec
where ec in (1,2);
```

The comma (,) in the `FROM` clause is short notation for `CROSS JOIN`.
`LATERAL` is assumed automatically for table functions like `unnest()`.

Rewrite `WHERE` to use `ARRAY` as parameter

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM
  t45407507 x,unnest(c) ec
WHERE ec = ANY(ARRAY[1,2]);
```